# How to Generate formatted Alpha Numeric strings in C#

Tags: c#

I want to generate random string with 5 alpha numeric  characters, But should generate two characters and other should be numeric like

```
 RL589
```

For that I have done like

```
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var stringChars = new char[5];
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
        }

        var finalString = new String(stringChars);
```

But i get confused how to arrange first two letters  be characters and next other should be numeric. Please help me anyone.

Comment: Two character string one with a-z the other 0-9, or the first two chars use a random number for your index 0-25 and the last three a random number between 26 - 35?

Comment: Waiting for "I also need them to be unique"... ^_^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two loops, for example like this:

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var numbers = "0123456789";
var stringChars = new char[5];
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
for (int i = 2; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
  stringChars[i] = numbers[random.Next(numbers.Length)];
}

var finalString = new String(stringChars);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generate two strings. One of characters and one of numbers. Then, concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var numbers = "0123456789";

var stringChars = new char[5];

var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < 2)
    {
        stringChars[i] = letters[random.Next(letters.Length)];
    }
    else
    {
        stringChars[i] = numbers[random.Next(numbers.Length)];
    }
}

var finalString = new String(stringChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need any strings.** Just use the implicit conversions between `char` and `int`:

```
var stringChars = new char[5];
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = (char)random.Next('A', 'Z');
}
for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = (char)random.Next('0', '9');
}

var finalString = new String(stringChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the Random object to create a random number?

```
var stringChars = new StringBuilder();
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    stringChars.Append((char)random.Next('A', 'Z'));
}

var finalString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", stringChars.ToString()
    , random.Next(1, 9)
    , random.Next(1, 9)
    , random.Next(1, 9));
```

or simply

```
var finalString = string.Format("{0}{1}", stringChars.ToString()
        , random.Next(100, 999));
```

Why StringBuilder, string concatenation always creates a new instance so you should avoid that.